# Login with cookie doesn't work on mobile safari

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I'm using this script to create a login system for my page.

http://php-login.net/demo3.html

The user can check a "keep me logged in"-box, and the script then saves the user login details in a cookie. Everything works fine in chrome, firefox, explorer and Safari on desktop, but on mobile safari the cookie login process fails.

I can echo out the cookie value, so I know that cookie it is set, but the login still fails.

Here's the script that sets the cookie:

```
private function newRememberMeCookie()
{
    // if database connection opened
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        // generate 64 char random string and store it in current user data
        $random_token_string = hash('sha256', mt_rand());
        $sth = $this->db_connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_rememberme_token = :user_rememberme_token WHERE user_id = :user_id");
        $sth->execute(array(':user_rememberme_token' => $random_token_string, ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));

        // generate cookie string that consists of userid, randomstring and combined hash of both
        $cookie_string_first_part = $_SESSION['user_id'] . ':' . $random_token_string;
        $cookie_string_hash = hash('sha256', $cookie_string_first_part . COOKIE_SECRET_KEY);
        $cookie_string = $cookie_string_first_part . ':' . $cookie_string_hash;

        // set cookie
        setcookie('rememberme', $cookie_string, time() + COOKIE_RUNTIME, "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
```

Here's the code to login byt cookie:

```
private function loginWithCookieData()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE['rememberme'])) {
        // extract data from the cookie
        list ($user_id, $token, $hash) = explode(':', $_COOKIE['rememberme']);


        // check cookie hash validity
        if ($hash == hash('sha256', $user_id . ':' . $token . COOKIE_SECRET_KEY) && !empty($token)) {
            // cookie looks good, try to select corresponding user
            if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
                // get real token from database (and all other data)
                $sth = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id
                                                  AND user_rememberme_token = :user_rememberme_token AND user_rememberme_token IS NOT NULL");
                $sth->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->bindValue(':user_rememberme_token', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->execute();
                // get result row (as an object)
                $result_row = $sth->fetchObject();

                if (isset($result_row->user_id)) {
                    // write user data into PHP SESSION [a file on your server]
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                    $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = 1;

                    // declare user id, set the login status to true
                    $this->user_id = $result_row->user_id;
                    $this->user_name = $result_row->user_name;
                    $this->user_email = $result_row->user_email;
                    $this->user_is_logged_in = true;

                    // Cookie token usable only once
                    $this->newRememberMeCookie();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // A cookie has been used but is not valid... we delete it
        $this->deleteRememberMeCookie();
        $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Invalid cookie'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more debug details: if you echo something after isset($_COOKIE...) does it show?

Comment: Well, quite strangely, I could echo out a test message the first time, but when I closes the browser and then opened up the page again the message whas not there...maybe this is because, the seconf time, the script logged in with with session information. The cookie login is only uses when the session has expired, ie after fiteen minutes.

Comment: if you use chrome you can click F12 and go to the Resources tab. There you can see all the cookies, expire time and values. The session (PHP) is mostly set up to end after browser closes the last window. Try to close - open up and see if there is still the cookie.

Comment: No, if I close all windows in chrome the cookie is not there anymore, and i'm not logged in. I have to log in again to set the cookie.

Comment: Ok, so what's the value of COOKIE_RUNTIME? if I got your problem right - you want the user to stay logged in - the cookie should stay, it's possible the time is not set right.